# For-loop for clicking web element

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop

I'm trying to loop the for loop 7 times where the webelement will be click 7 times only. Even if there are other commentsbutton element in the web page, the loop will ignore them and stop clicking.

Currently, the script will still click on the webelement non-stop.

```
 WebElement commentsbutton = (WebElement) comment.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButton -cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButtonEnabled')]")); //view all/ load more comments

//click more comments
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    //for (WebElement comments_element : commentsbutton) {
    commentsbutton.click(); //click on button if found
    Thread.sleep(3000); //pause for 5 seconds   
    System.out.println(commentsbutton);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Do you need to be finding the next element each iteration?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser i just have to find this same element for 7 times and ignore the others if there are more than 7 of these elements.

Comment: does your page contain 7 or more commentsButton when the page is open? or does the 2nd commentButton appear after clicking on the 1st comment button?

Comment: @Striker the second commentbutton will appear after clicking on the first comment button.

Comment: All the commentButton has the same xpath?

Comment: @Striker yes, all the commentbutton has the same xpath.

Comment: your for loop is just fine. I don't see why the element is getting clicked non-stop. Try cleaning and compiling the code again.

Comment: @Striker Tried cleaning and compiling the code again, but still doesnt stop clicking the element after 7 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

for(int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    WebElement element = wait.until(
       ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
           By.xpath("//button[@class='-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButtonEnabled']")));

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButtonEnabled']")).click();
}
```

**Explanation:** As per the comments below, you mentioned that you actually wanted to click on the `load more comments` button on a Instagram [post](https://instagram.com/p/643S2iiY1E/) for exactly 7 times. So, if you observe the HTML of the page, especially that of the button, is:

```
<button class="-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButton -cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButtonEnabled">
```

But once you click the button, the site start fetching more comments to display. In that period, the class name value `-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButtonEnabled` is removed the HTML becomes this:

```
<button class="-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButton" disabled="true">
```

Once it fetches the data and displays it, the class name value which was removed is added back and the button gets enabled.

Hence, if you want to click on the button multiple times to load all or most of the comments, you are gonna have to use a combination of [waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) and loops. You were using `Thread.sleep()` to give a pause and then click on the button. But then using a wait is a better option, since it polls the DOM to find the element for that period of time and once it meets it expected condition (in this case visibility of the element), it then moves on to execute the next line of code.

Comment: i added `List<Webelement>` to commentsbutton7 and this error of **"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 6"**

Comment: @dark_space - Try printing the length of the list. `commentsbutton.size()`. I think it is fetching less than 7 elements. If so, then you need to check your xPath.

Comment: tried printing the list length but still have the same **IndexOutOfBoundsException** error and nothing prints out.

Comment: @dark_space - Is the spelling of `findElements` correct? Normally, people make that mistake. Please check if the code is correct especially the first line of code of my answer.

Comment: yes, its correct. i tried reading on sublist and ways to solve the error but still didnt manage to solve it and get the code to work.

Comment: @dark_space - I guess, you should have a look at xPath you've generated. I guess, that is causing a problem.

Comment: i have changed the it `List<WebElement> commentsbutton = comment.findElements(By.className("-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__comment"));` instead and managed to print 6 of these elements. but they are not being clicked on. @jason

Comment: Try keeping it simple. Try this `findElements(By.xpath("//button[@class='-cx-PRIVATE-PostInfo__commentsLoadMoreButtonEnabled']"));`

Comment: @dark_space - Do count the number of elements it finds and confirm by the number of elements you want on the screen.

Comment: the IndexOutOfBoundsException error appeared using the xpath you have provided @jason

Comment: I'm gonna need to have a look at your HTML source code. Do add your code on gist.github.com and paste the link here.

Comment: @dark_space - I'm gonna need the complete HTML source code.

Comment: i'm sorry, i think it would be very messy to copy exactly the complete HTML source code so is it alright if i just give you the web page instead? https://instagram.com/p/643S2iiY1E/

Comment: @dark_space - I understood what you wanted to achieve since you've given me the link. I've edited the answer, do have a look. Let me know if you still face an issue.

Comment: thank you so much! the code works exactly like how i wanted. but may i know why the previous code that uses sublist couldnt work and whats wrong with the code i had written above?

Comment: @dark_space - Well, initially I thought there were multiple buttons with the same class name and you wanted to click the first seven. Hence, I suggested to use `findElements()` and `subList()`. But once you gave me the link, I then realized it was a single button. I'll be editing the answer for more explanation.